# MultiPoint Bluetooth Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, multipoint

Consider the BluetoothChat sample. I'd like to provide the possibility to allow multiple simultaneous Bluetooth connection into a peer.

Are there additional actions to simple Bluetooth connection required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same purpose you need to do query in a thread. You need discovery device on particular time period and then once you found do the connection with that device. after connection again start device discovery & so on. This way you can connect with multiple devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The example below does exactly what you said.
[BluetoothChatMulti](https://github.com/polyclef/BluetoothChatMulti)

Comment: Are you sure you can connect 2 media devices with audio profile for example at the same time? :)