# Can bluetooth connect two same devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project that requires Bluetooth, however I need it to connect with Bluetooth from my app on one phone to my app on another phone.
Is there a way for Bluetooth to be used on two devices of the same type, or is is just different devices that can connect to each other? Could you please also provide me with a link to Android documentation, if possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MultiPoint Bluetooth Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062531/multipoint-bluetooth-connection)

Answer (score 0):

> When using BLE, an Android device can act as a peripheral device, a central device, or both. Peripheral mode lets devices send advertisement packets. Central mode lets devices scan for advertisements

See [Device modes](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble#device-modes).

[BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser) enables to turn a supported phone into a peripheral.

See [Bluetooth Low Energy Advertising](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising) for details.